# Powershell EWS Nested search filter

Tags: powershell, messaging, exchangewebservices, searchfiltercollection

I'm trying to perform a search filter using EWS on a function based on Powershell.
I would like to mix AND & OR due i mix different properties, i've tried the method below but it didn't work as expected:

```
                    $sfCollectionAND = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And)
                    $sfCollectionAND .add($SenderAddress1)
                    $sfCollectionAND .add($SenderAddress2)

$sfCollectionOR = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::Or)
                    $sfCollectionOR .add($sfCollectionAND)
                    $sfCollectionOR .add($ReceiveDate1)
                    $sfCollectionOR .add($ReceiveDate2)
```

Basically the filter purpose is 1st gather message between period of time and then exclude 2 senders.

Comment: Where are the `$SenderAddress*` and `$ReceiveData*` variables coming from? Are they proper search filters?

Comment: Those variables contains the Date and sender address, they works fine since i use them all together under AND operator, however since i would like exclude different senders i need to make use of AND & OR

Comment: As per the documentation on EWS, the SearchFilterCollection only has a single property for the logical condition for all of the filters contained.  I don't think you can do this using a SearchFilterCollection.  You could do one side of the search (and/or) and then iterate through the results executing the other side of the search through code.